# Is It possible to read serialization data in android which made by iphone development

Tags: android, iphone

I have one file which is create in iPhone using serialization object. and i want to do read in android. Is it possible or not? please reply fast in advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the serialized data is in a pList.

See this http://code.google.com/p/plist/

Comment: Well, grab that library!  It's released under a very permissive license (MIT) and is really easy to use.  See the examples page.  Being familiar with basic NextStep objects, especially NSDicitionary and NSData will help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read any file generated by another language. It's better if there's a library out there for it. It'll get complicated if the file uses arrays, especially dynamic ones. This may require some fun time with a hex editor. I can't guarantee reliability with this method though if the data isn't simple. Just realize that this may end up being a tricky task

It's better to have a file spec made. You don't have to use a binary file, as you can use something like JSON or XML if it's all text-based information.